# I am stuck with PHP's array()?

Tags: php, arrays, function, parameters

Why is the following `array()` passed into a function. I am not able to understand the `array()` function.
I know if $_POST doesn't have any value, it will pass `array()`, but what is the value in `array()`?

```
SomeFunction($_POST ? $_POST : array());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array()` isn't a function per se, it's a language construct. But simply using `array()` will create an empty array for you, that is, with zero elements.

You probably want to check for:

```
isset($_POST) ? $_POST : array()
```

Edit:

As pointed out by greg, `$_POST` will always be set. So there is no need to check for it and return an empty array. `someFunc($_POST)` should do exactly the same thing.

Comment: $_POST should always be set unless you're in an ancient PHP, in which case there are better things to do than pretend there was no POST data.

Comment: yes, you're right. haven't thought of that. but that means that this question is totally ridiculous, because an empty $_POST will be at least an empty array

Comment: I think you mean:

empty($_POST) ? array() : $_POST

Comment: @Josh: The result is the same. $_POST is always set, and if it doesn't contain any variables it'll be an empty array. So the whole test is unnecessary.

Comment: @Machine, yes, I just realized that and posted a comment to that effect. This code is somewhat flawed :-)

Answer (score 7):

[array()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) is not a function, it's a [language construct to create a new array](http://se.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). If no arguments (excuse the function terminology) are given, an empty array is created. The difference between PHP arrays and say... Java arrays are that PHP arrays are dynamically resized as new elements are added. But the array()-construct also takes parameters as a comma-separated list of *key=>value-pairs*.

So, you can create arrays in the following ways:

```
$empty = array();
$autoIndexed = array (1, 2, 3);
$associative = array('key1' => 1, 'key2' => 2);

var_dump($empty, $autoIndexed, $associative);

// Prints:
Array ()
Array (
   [0] => 1
   [1] => 2
   [2] => 3
)
Array (
   [key1] => 1
   [key2] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just passing in an empty array if $_POST doesn't evaluate to `true`.
Why, I don't know...

Comment: My question is that, what that empty array conatian? Does that contain zero value..?

Comment: An empty array doesn't contain anything.

Comment: @Syed, the function SomeFunction() expects an array and the code you provided is a (poor) attempt at ensuring that an array is passed to SomeFunction() -- either $_POST, or an empty array